# JQuery reposition error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem. I want to reposition my error message for my password checken. I want to see the message under my form button. So I tried to set an errorLabelContainer with a  but its not working can anybody help me to figure out the problem?

HTML:

```
<form name="f" id="f" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/setpassword" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="password">Passwort</label>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="password_again">Passwort wiederholen</label>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input class="left" type='password' id="password_again" name="password_again" size="20" />


            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align="center">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="errorMsg"> </div>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$( "#f" ).validate({
      rules: {
        password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
        },
        password_again: {
          equalTo: "#password"
        }
      }, 
      messages: {

        password: {
            required: "Bitte geben Sie Ihr Passwort zwei mal ein.",
            minlength: "Ihr Passwort muss aus mindestens 8 Zeichen bestehen."
            },

        password_again: {
            required: "Bitte geben Sie Ihr Passwort zwei mal ein.",
            equalTo: "Ihre Eingabe muss gleich sein."
            }
      },
      errorLabelContainer: '#errorMsg',
      wrapper: 'li'

});
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You can do that with some CSS, did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<div>` has the *class* `errorMsg`, but you are searching for an element with the *id* `errorMsg`.